# django model form inheritance

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using django modelform inheritence in my modelform but it seems to be not working here is my code sample

```
class ArticleForm(forms.ModelForm):
  title = forms.CharField(required=True)
  sites = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=True, queryset= Sites.objects.all().order_by('name'), widget=forms.SelectMultiple())

class ArticleAddForm(ArticleForm):
   class Meta(ArticleForm.Meta):
       exclude = ('sites',)
```

i want to exclude "sites" from "ArticleAddForm" but while validating it is raising form validation error sites field required please help?

Comment: That's because the 'sites' field has required=True

Comment: @pram but i want sites field required = True in ArticleForm, is there any other way to sort it out?

Answer (score 2):

ModelForms don't handle inheritance so well, I believe.

Probably the best ou can do is remove the `required` flag in the child class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ArticleAddForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.base_fields['sites'].required = False
    self.base_fields['sites'].widget = HiddenInput() # if you want
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you need to initialize the ArticleAddForm with an Article object to fill the blank fields, i.e. the excluded fields. For example:

```
sites = Sites.objects.all()    # modify this according to your needs
article = Article(title='', sites=sites)
form = ArticleAddForm(request.POST, instance=article)
form.save()
```