# how to get modelform data in another class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model like this:

```
class WalkDb(models.Model):
USERNAME=models.CharField("name",max_length=20)
..........
```

a form like this:

```
class WalkDbForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = WalkDb
```

and i create a class which wanted to get the data form

```
class WALK:
def __init__(self):
    self.db=WalkDb
    self.walkform=WalkDbForm
def emptyForm(self):
    return self.walkform
```

in the views.py

```
def add(request):
return render_to_response('add.html',{'addForm': WALK.emptyForm()})
```

but the page add.html did not print everything, and has no any error message.
how can i fetch the WalkDbForm in another class?
Thank You!

Comment: The link django model from inheritance which you give can not solves my question.
I just want to integrate the data module class and form module class into one class.
like the WALK class, by the future, i can use the WALK class , like this 
WALK.db.xxxxx or WALK.form.xxxxxx
the all needed method integrate to just one class for easy to use.
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? And, especially, why would you do this with a class? Modules are the correct way of organizing related classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i'm getting the idea but still i think i found something somewhat similar to your question:

[django model form inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12645875/django-model-form-inheritance)

Please check that link and let us know if that solves your question.

Honestly i don't see an actual use on this question.